# jpeg R package instalation does not find jpeglib.h in non standard location

Tags: r, linux, installation, libjpeg

I'm trying to install `jpeg` package in R in a Linux server (in which I don't have sudo access) and `jpeg` installation does not find `jpeglib.h` I installed locally. How do I tell R where to look for it when `configure.args='--with-libjpeg-include=/path` failed?

Sever OS version is CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

In R I ran:

```
>install.packages('jpeg', lib="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/lib", repos="https://mirrors.nic.cz/R/", destdir="/shared/mybossusr/usr/tmp")
```

And I got this error:

> rjcommon.h:11:21: fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory
>    #include

So I installed jpeg-turbo

```
wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo-2.0.2.tar.gz
mkdir libjpeg-turbo-2
cd libjpeg-turbo-2
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/shared/mybossusr/bin/libjpeg-turbo-2 /shared/mybossusr/download/libjpeg-turbo-2.0.2
make
make install
```

I checked and `jpeglib.h` is at `/shared/mybossusr/bin/libjpeg-turbo-2/include`

I added this at the end of my `~/.bashrc` :

```
export CFLAGS="-I/usr/include -I=/shared/mybossusr/bin/libjpeg-turbo-2"
```

I logged out and in, and I got the same error when trying to install `jpeg` in R.
I also added the location of the library to my path at `~/.barsh`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/shared/mybossusr/bin/libjpeg-turbo-2/include
export PATH=$PATH:/shared/mybossusr/bin/libjpeg-turbo-2/include
```

just in case, because I don't fully understand when a software looks where. Did `source ~/.bashrc`, logged out and in, but nothing changed.

So, I tried afterwards in R some arguments I came up with:

```
install.packages('jpeg', lib="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/lib", repos="https://mirrors.nic.cz/R/", destdir="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/tmp", configure.args='--with-libjpeg-include=/shared/mybossuser/bin/jpeg/include')
```

and:

```
install.packages('jpeg', lib="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/lib", repos="https://mirrors.nic.cz/R/", destdir="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/tmp", configure.args='--with-libjpeg=/shared/mybossuser/bin/jpeg')
```

or:

```
install.packages('jpeg', lib="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/lib", repos="https://mirrors.nic.cz/R/", destdir="/shared/mybossusr/R3.5.0/tmp", configure.args='--with-libjpeg-lib=/shared/mybossuser/bin/jpeg/include')
```

to try to tell R where `libjpeg` was installed, but nothing worked.

Is there any `configure.args` that will do the trick? So far with other packages it was quite straight forward to use a `--with-package_name-lib`, but I'm clueless with this one...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not an expert in Linux but have you tried adding the location of `jpeglib.h` to your path? As far as I know `R` will look there for installed libraries...

Comment: Thanks JBGruber, I already did. It says so in the post, but I'm going to edit it so it's more clear

Comment: @Mosky have you found a solution for this? Same issue, I tried installing ggmap on RHEL, failed due to the jpeglib.h

Comment: @Afiq Johari Unfortunately no, I was kind of in a rush so I gave up and ended up running the analysis in a local computer in which I am sudo and even if it was slower, I did not have any problem.

Answer (score 4):

Try installing the `libjpeg-turbo-devel` package. That's what did it for me on RHEL 7. According to [this page](https://pkgs.org/download/libjpeg-devel), on CentOS 7 the package name is the same.

Comment: rhel8, same error and same solution.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what did the trick:

Install jpeg-turbo in a non-standard location, say `$HOME/local`, from:

https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo/releases

```
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/local
make
make install
```

Then point these globals to the install location in your `.bashrc`:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib64:$HOME/local/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib64:$HOME/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$HOME/local/include:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
```

Then try the R package again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the config.args in the `install.packages()` command in R - for some reason `--with-libjpeg-include` doesn't point the compiler to the non-standard location I speficied. So here's how I worked around it.

First, I installed `libjpeg` ([link](https://github.com/LuaDist/libjpeg)) in a non-standard location.

```
# in bash: 
cd 
mkdir /home/tpytsui/libjpeg
cd /home/tpytsui/libjpeg
# download libjpeg.zip into cd
unzip libjpeg.zip
cd /home/tpytsui/libjpeg/libjpeg-master
./configure --prefix=/home/tpytsui/libjpeg/local
make
# make test # run make test to ensure no complaints
make install
```

Then, I added the path to my libjpeg to LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

```
# in bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/tpytsui/libjpeg/local/lib
```

Then, in R, I told the c compiler (in my case gcc) where to look when compiling files. Normally, we shouldn't do this, but we are only doing this because configure.args doesn't work.

```
# in R
Sys.setenv(C_INCLUDE_PATH = "/home/tpytsui/libjpeg/local/include")
Sys.setenv(LIBRARY_PATH = "/home/tpytsui/libjpeg/local/lib")
```

Finally, I installed the r package `jpeg`. There is no need to add config.args because they didn't work anyway.

```
# in R
install.packages('jpeg', type='source', repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com")
```